# "echo" in .bat is quite slow

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

I wrote a little .bat file, hoping to be able to create a matrix-like (0 and 1) output.

The problem is, that it is pretty slow, it takes nearly two seconds to fill one line.

Is there something I can do to get it run **faster**?

Matrix.bat:

```
@echo off
color 02

:start
if %random% LSS 16384 (
echo|set /p=1
) else (
echo|set /p=0
)
goto start
```

Comment: Btw. You don't use `echo` to output anything, you use `set /p` with a pipe. And pipes slows down the speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

echo is very slow. So build your line without echoing the single chars, then echo the whole line at once.
Another trick: `set /a "l=!random! &1"` uses the last Bit from `!random!` only (so it gives either `0`or `1`). This is quicker than processing Integer.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:start
set line=
for /L %%i in (1,1,80) do (
    set /a "l=!random! &1"
    set line=!line!!l!
  ) 
  echo !line! 
)
goto start
```

Comment: Thank you, echoing a whole line at once lead to a big performance improvement