# How to have multiple sums in a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix this one works below) but is slow as it has to loop every number. So i was wondering if you can have multiple %random% %% 2 without just a "(random number) %2" being printed.

`@echo off 
color 0a
:a 
set /a mat=%random% %% 2
echo |set /p=%mat%
goto a`

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18185785/2152082) (one of my first answers on this site)

Comment: @Dennis van Gils was around 12% faster when writing to a text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this to be much faster:

```
@echo off
if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit/b
color 0a
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:a
set "addition="
for /L %%i in (1,1,256) do (
set /a mat=!random! %% 2
set addition=!addition!!mat!
)
echo |set /p=%addition%
goto a
```

EDIT: I now see that the answer @Stephan links to in the comments is very similar, so credit goes to him too.

EDIT #2:

You might like this one too, has all kind of characters so it looks a bit more "matrixy"

```
@echo off
if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit/b
color a
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "CHARS=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@@@###$$$%%%%%%***  "
echo %CHARS%>x&for %%? in (x) do set /a strlength=%%~z? - 2&del x
:a
call :randomString addition 100 "%chars%" %strlength%
echo |set /p=%addition%
goto a

:randomString
set "length=%2"
set "CHARS=%~3"
if ["%CHARS%"]==[""] set "CHARS=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@@@###$$$%%%%%%***"
set "strlength=%4"
if [%strlength%]==[] echo %CHARS%>x&for %%? in (x) do set /a strlength=%%~z? - 2&del x
set "line="
for /L %%a in (1 1 %length%) do (
set /a "randnr=!random!%%!strlength!"
for /l %%n in (!randnr! 1 !randnr!) do set "line=!line!!CHARS:~%%n,1!"
)
set %1=%line%
exit /b
```

For extra effect add 6 spaces to the CHARS variable. Note that I also added a line to start it in full-screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

The method below is the fastest possible way to solve this problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Prepare the output for one line
set "bin=0101010101"
set "line="
for /L %%i in (1,1,79) do (
   set "line=!line!%%bin:~^!random:~-1^!,1%%"
)

for /L %%i in () do call echo %line%
```

Comment: But this uses echo and a hardcoded width. If your terminal's width is changed this won't look nice anymore...